# How to get bundleclass that is registered in Application.e4xmi when new MPart is created - Eclipse RCP e4

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

How to get bundleclass that is registered in Application.e4xmi when new MPart is created dynamically:

```
EPartService lService = (EPartService)Activator.getContext().getServiceReference(EPartService.class);
    MPart lPart = lService.showPart(pViewId, PartState.CREATE);
    //pass some initial parameters to lPart...
```

or how to pass some parameters to the bundleclass of new MPart

Answer (score 1):

Call the `getObject()` method of `MPart` to get the class created for the part:

```
MyPartClass partObject = (MyPartClass)lpart.getObject();
```

Note: You should inject the `EPartService` in to your handler rather than trying to get it via `getServiceReference`. There are multiple part services and you need to get the correct one.

Comment: Can I get somehow current EPartService and get rid off all this crazy injection which works only if some bindings are linked in application.e4xmi?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can use `ContextInjectionFactory` to do injection on your own classes.

Comment: As I cant find could You help how to use ContextInjectionFactory with own classes (not connected to application model) without using any of application-model connected objects and get EPartService?

Comment: That is really a new question. You have to use ContextInjectionFactory from something that has the current IEclipseContext. That can be things connected to the application model (parts, command handlers etc.) or created from the LifeCycle class. You can also get the IEclipseContext from things like an MPart.